# Generate automatic Id

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

I am making a web application which uses a database in which I have a field I_ID which i want to automatically increment like I0 then I1 then I2 and so on with each record insertion in the database.

To achieve it I made a trigger for this table.But its not working fine.What can be the reason.Please help

My Trigger T1:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER  "T1" 
before
insert on "TBINDIVIDUAL"
for each row
declare 
x varchar2(10);
mx varchar2(13);
mx2 varchar2(13);
y number(3);
begin
x:=:new.I_ID;
mx:=substr(x,1,1);
select max(I_ID) into mx2 from tbindividual where I_ID like mx||'%';
y:=to_number(substr(mx2,2));
:new.I_ID:=mx||to_char(y+1);
end t1;
/
```

EDITED : 
As i do by answer

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER  "TBINDIVIDUAL_T1" 
BEFORE
insert on "TBINDIVIDUAL"
for each row
begin
:new.I_ID = SEQ1.nextval;
end;
/
```

But it give two errors

Encountered the symbol "=" when expecting one of the following: := . ( @ % ; indicator

Encountered the symbol "END"

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So Oracle is not SQL Server...
if you want to get unique ID's, you need to populate them from a sequence.

for creating a sequence use:

```
create sequence myseq;
```

and in your code use (depends on the version):

```
:new.I_ID := myseq.nextval;
```

or

```
select myseq.nextval into :new.I_ID from dual;
```

the problem your code doesn't work is what :new and :old means...
I would recommend you reading about their meaning...

Hope I've been helpful...

---

Because of the discussion in the comments - here is a full example:
for this table:

```
CREATE TABLE test (A number);
```

to add a unique, sequential ID you need to first create a sequence:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE myseq;
```

and a trigger:

`CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER  "T1" 
before
insert on "test"
for each row
begin
:new.I_ID := myseq.nextval;
end t1;
/`

by the way - I would recommend to check before substituting :new.I_ID, if it is null or not, cause sometimes in upgrades people add a unique ID from an external resource.. (such as them getting a unique number from the sequence themselves...)

you can read more about sequences here:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_6015.htm#SQLRF01314

sorry for the way the code is displayed.. need to learn how to write code here...

One more thing - In Oracle - you cannot create such a PL/SQL to increase existing counter without locks.
Concurrent queries might run the first query in the PL/SQL simultaneously, which means multiple sessions will get the same I_ID.

Also notice that in your code you queried the max on varchar, which is not the same as max on number...

---

Adding concatenated text is unrelated to the unique ID. In your case it will look like:

`:new.I_ID = substr(:new.I_ID,1,1)||to_char(myseq.nextval);`

assuming x is being inputted with the char you want..

Comment: sorry i didnt get you

Comment: Oracle has a unique identifier mechanism called "sequence".
it's and object that creates unique id's.

So you need to create this object in the DB - it's like a table, unrelated to the PL/SQL within the trigger. you can use it wherever you want.

Within your PL/SQL you can use it in version 11 (maybe 10g2 too) and above in the first manner I wrote, and in earlier versions in the second manner.

Comment: could you please write modified trigger ?am working on oracle 10g.so later one will be helpful to me

Comment: I'll try creating a more useful answer with full example.

Comment: by the way - I don't have an Oracle on the current computer - so excuse me if there are small syntax issues .. but the concept works...

Comment: I want "I" also at the begining of each number

Comment: by the way - if you want only the letter I, you can use 'I'|| .. instead of the substr(: ... I wrote above.

Comment: I tried your code but it gives some errors. i edited it in my post too..Please help also in select myseq.nextval into :new.I_ID from dual; statement whats dual ?

Comment: the problem here was = instead of := (I'm sorry for the syntax errors.. I don't have an oracle here to debug..)

Comment: and dual is a dummy table, that contains one record, if you want for example to query a function - that's the way to do it.. example: select sysdate from dual; will give you the current time.

Comment: and last question..how to change :new.I_ID = substr(:new.I_ID,1,1)||to_char(myseq.nextval); if myseq.nextval dont work and select myseq.nextval into :new.I_ID from dual; works

Comment: SO the first should work, after you'll fix my syntax error.. 
and the way to do it is to declare a number variable in the "DECLARE" area, select into that variable, and afterwards to concatenate it: DECLARE a number; begin select seq.nextval into a from dual; :new.I_ID := 'I'|| to_char(a); ....

Comment: is it ok acc to you ? CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER  "T1" 
before
insert on "TBINDIVIDUAL"
for each row
declare 
a number;
begin
begin select SEQ1.nextval into a from dual;
:new.I_ID := 'I'|| to_char(a);
end t1;
/
ALTER TRIGGER  "T1" ENABLE
/

Comment: Yes. note that there are two begins, and only one end - so remove one of the begins...

Comment: thanx..for help ..+1 for ur explanation